# React. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react/js so I expect that I am using useEffect completely incorrectly here, but if someone couple point me in the right direction that would be great :).

The code I am trying to write is to set an element to a const called HomeScreen depending on a role selected by a user when they log in.

```
function WorkflowTemplate({ Logout }) {
const user = useContext(userContext);

const [HomeScreen, setHomeScreen] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("starting useEffect role select");
    switch (user.role) {
        case "Chemistry":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFChemistry />), console.log(HomeScreen);
        case "Micro":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFMicro />), console.log(HomeScreen);
        case "Manager":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFManager />);
        case "Sample admin":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFSampleAdmin />);
        case "Developer":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFDev />);
        default:
            console.log("error with role select");
    }
});
```

This above code is returning Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Router.Consumer`.

However, before trying to implement useEffect I had

```
function WorkflowTemplate({ Logout }) {
const user = useContext(userContext);
const HomeScreen = () => {
    console.log("running HomeScreen function");
    switch (user.role) {
        case "Chemistry":
            return <WFChemistry />;
        case "Micro":
            return <WFMicro />;
        case "Manager":
            return <WFManager />;
        case "Sample admin":
            return <WFSampleAdmin />;
        case "Developer":
            return <WFDev />;
        default:
            return console.log("error with role switch");
    }
}
```

This worked fine, expect it was being called every time the component was rendered which is undesirable.

What am I doing incorrectly with my useEffect function?

Thank you in advance,

Greg

Comment: In your second case HomeScreen is a callable function.  In the first case you have already called the components and it is just a JSX element.  So you need to render it as {HomeScreen} instead of <HomeScreen/>

Answer (score 0):

try to add an initial value to your state (example: null) like: `const [HomeScreen, setHomeScreen] = useState(null)`

and if you don't want your component to render every time then you can pass a empty array in your `useEffect` which means only render it once:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("starting useEffect role select");
    switch (user.role) {
        case "Chemistry":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFChemistry />), console.log(HomeScreen);
        case "Micro":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFMicro />), console.log(HomeScreen);
        case "Manager":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFManager />);
        case "Sample admin":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFSampleAdmin />);
        case "Developer":
            return setHomeScreen(<WFDev />);
        default:
            console.log("error with role select");
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Component` vs. `<Component/>`

There is a difference between the Component itself and the JSX element which is returned from calling it as `<Component/>`  In your first code, the value of your `HomeScreen` variable is a JSX element, so you don't need to call it again.  You just need to render it, like so:

```
<SomeParent>
   {HomeScreen}
</SomeParent>
```

When you attempt to call it as `<HomeScreen/>` then you will get the error that you've posted.

In your second example, `HomeScreen` is a function so it is ok to call `<HomeScreen/>`.  You are essentially creating a function component within your component.  You are right that this is bad for performance.

Your `useEffect` isn't any better though because it has no dependencies so it will re-run on every render.  It should depend on `user.role`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Later on in the code I am using a <Router><Switch> as part of the navigation, in here I render the component as {HomeScreen}. Am I able to set HomeScreen to a component using that switch above? I am not sure of the syntax for how to do this?
Thanks for reminding me about the 2nd arg for useEffect :)
Edit: the console reads out HomeScreen as being undefined when going through the switch, so I assume I am not setting it to a component correctly? I tried setHomeScreen({component}) but this didn't work either